# Skip listener not called in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, skip

I have a step with custom skip management.
I defined a skip policy which source code is the following:

```
public class CustomSkipPolicy implements SkipPolicy {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable throwable, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
            return true;
    }
}
```

My Skip listener is the following:

```
@Component
public class JoueurSkipListener implements SkipListener<Object, Object> {

    @Autowired
    private LogImportRejetRepository logImportRejetRepository;

    @Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable throwable) {

        saveLogImportRejet(Optional.empty(), throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(Object deltaObject, Throwable throwable) {
        saveLogImportRejet(Optional.of(deltaObject), throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(Object deltaObject, Throwable throwable) {
        saveLogImportRejet(Optional.of(deltaObject), throwable);
    }



    private void saveLogImportRejet(Optional<Object> deltaObject, Throwable throwable){

        LogImportRejet logImportRejet = LogImportRejet.builder()
                .createTime(OffsetDateTime.now())
                .typeImport(TypeImportEnum.JOUEUR)
                .motifRejet(throwable.getLocalizedMessage())
                .ligne(deltaObject.isPresent() ? deltaObject.get().toString(): null)
                .build();
        logImportRejetRepository.save(logImportRejet);
    }

}
```

My step definition is the following:

```
@Bean
    public Step stepImportJoueur(@Qualifier("joueurReader") ItemReader<IJoueurFed> joueurReader, @Qualifier("joueurWriter") ItemWriter<Joueur> joueurWriter, @Qualifier("joueurProcessor") JoueurProcessor joueurProcessor,
                                 @Qualifier("joueurSkipListener")  SkipListener joueurSkipListener) {
        SimpleStepBuilder<IJoueurFed, Joueur> builder = stepBuilderFactory.get("stepImportJoueur")
                .<IJoueurFed, Joueur>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(joueurReader)
                .processor(joueurProcessor)
                .writer(joueurWriter)
                .faultTolerant()
                .retryLimit(retryLimit)
                .retry(ConnectTimeoutException.class)
                .retry(DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.class)
                .skipPolicy(new CustomSkipPolicy());
        return builder.listener(joueurSkipListener).build();
    }
```

I have a constraint violation exception that i want to skip. But, the listener nor the skip policy is not called.

Answer (score 1):

I have a unique constraint in the database table that causes constraint violation exception when trying to write into the database.
Although the exception occurred, the step always has the status completed.
This is why my skip listener isn't called.
To solve this issue, i created a custom writer that calls entityManager.flush() after the write method of the parent is called.
After doing this, the exception is thrown and my skip listener is called.
I have posted a code snippet in this stackoverflow thread:
[Spring batch error handling with JPA transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866715/spring-batch-error-handling-with-jpa-transaction/70187662)